# Update python to a specific version using conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Currently I have anaconda3 installed in my server with the following version:

Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)

I want to update the Python to Python 3.5.1.

I know that `conda update python` updates python to latest version, but I want to update it to only 3.5.1.  What will be the command for it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried `conda install python=3.5.1`? It deals with the current root environment instead of creating a separate one.